# How to fix photocapture error with vuforia, script in unity for hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens

I am trying to take a photo through the Hololens with my PhotoCapture unity script. I want to use a Vuforia Engine ARCamera for the possibility to see the reality at the same time as I see the AR-GUI I've created (for future functionality).

The main error I get is:

> Failed capturing photo (hr = 0xC00D3704)

**Why does it occur? How do I fix it?**

> The FocusManager singleton has not been initialized.
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Assert(Boolean, String)
>   HoloToolkit.Unity.Singleton`1:AssertIsInitialized() (at
>   Assets/HoloToolkit/Common/Scripts/Singleton.cs:51)
>   HoloToolkit.Unity.CanvasHelper:Start() (at
>   Assets/HoloToolkit/Utilities/Scripts/CanvasHelper.cs:30)

is also an error occurring when starting the unity scene, but I haven't had it before...

This is code that I am using, placed on an ARCamera (have also tried out mixed reality camera with a vuforia behavior script and it didn't get the second error). Also, I want to apologize to the person who this code is borrowed from because I don't remember the link to your site.

```
public class PhotoCaptureExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;
    Texture2D targetTexture = null;
    public string path = "";
    CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();

void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("k"))
    {
        Debug.Log("k was pressed");

        Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
        targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);

        // Create a PhotoCapture object
        PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate (PhotoCapture captureObject)
        {
            photoCaptureObject = captureObject;
            cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
            cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

            // Activate the camera
            photoCaptureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(cameraParameters, delegate (PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
            {
                // Take a picture
                photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
            });
        });
    }
}

string FileName(int width, int height)
{
    return string.Format("screen_{0}x{1}_{2}.png", width, height, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"));
}

void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
{
    // Copy the raw image data into the target texture
    photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);

    Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();

    targetTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height), 0, 0);
    targetTexture.Apply();

    byte[] bytes = targetTexture.EncodeToPNG();

    string filename = FileName(Convert.ToInt32(targetTexture.width), Convert.ToInt32(targetTexture.height));
    //save to folder under assets
    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/Snapshots/" + filename, bytes);
    Debug.Log("The picture was uploaded");

    // Deactivate the camera
    photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
}

void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
{
    // Shutdown the photo capture resource
    photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
    photoCaptureObject = null;
}
}
```

It seems that I can't get to `OnCapturedPhotoToMemory` or if it breaks already by the method call. Trying it out again right now the code occasionally won't register that I have pushed `k` at all...

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: What has FocusManager  been set up as? is this really unityscript? it looks like plain c# to me

Comment: honestly I haven't got a clue what FocusManager is or where it comes from :S It didn't show up before, but might have occurred when I changed back to the ARCamera from holotoolkits mixedRealityCamera...

It is C# but is that not compatible with unity script (a script made in unity)?

Comment: Oh, sry I got the wrong tag!!!

Comment: Ok, but its telling you the focusmanager hasnt been setup, this seems to be the first point of the error?

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah. Following the error there are 3 calls to the `FocusManager.AssertIsInitialized();` 
One in SimpleSinglePointerSelector private void Start() method.
One in CanvasHelper private void Start() method.
And one in CanvaseditorExtention to check  "if we have a focus manager in our scene." I have not touched any of these.

Comment: well while I also have no idea what is on focusmanager, are there settings that need setting?

Comment: @BugFinder I felt something was off, so did a new unity project with the same settings. The focusManager error is now gone but the "failing to capture photo" is still there. Maybe we can focus on that error if you know anything about  or a way to understand how to fix it :)

Comment: not an expert but: do you have vuforia, have you tried sectioning the code off into a method not part of update? does it ever work or does it always do this?  what else do you have going on while this is happening?

Comment: @BugFinder It did not matter to put the code in its own method and calling it in the update. the code has not worked on a camera with `vuforia behaviour`. This is the only script I run in the project so far.

Comment: So I asked 5 things, got 1 answer..

Comment: Yes I have Vuforia, just updated it a day ago or so. This script has worked on a regular main camera but couldn't take more than one picture due to the `targetTexture.ReadPixels` line. Since changing to having an ARCamera aswell this error has always occurred. I do not have anything else going on in the project as I know of. @BugFinder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: Vuforia's `VuforiaBehaviour` on the camera holds the access on the device's real camera hardware => nothing else can use it meanwhile.

---

For fixing this you could use a dedicated camera for Vuforia (simply somewhere place a new GameObject e.g. `VuforiaCamera` in the scene and attach a `Camera` component as well as a `VuforiaBehaviour` to it.

[image]

On the Vuforia Camera set `Culling Mask` to `Nothing` (we don't render anything with that camera) and `Depth` to e.g. `-2` (higher values are rendered on top -> put this behind all other cameras).

[image]

You have to do this because otherwise Vuforia automatically adds it to the main camera (which we don't want to disable because then we don't see anything). By manually adding one to the scene Vuforia automatically uses that one instead.

Everywhere in your scene where you need a Camera ofcourse you use the original camera from the Holo-Tookit (your usual `MainCamera`). Problem you can't fully rely on `Camera.main` in scripts because on runtime the `VuforiaBehaviour` automatically marks its `Camera` as `MainCamera` as well ... (-_-) Vuforia ... so additionally I always disabled and enabled the `VuforiaBehaviour` along with the GameObject but maybe it is enough already to only disable and enable the GameObject. At least at GameStart it should be disabled I guess until everything relying on `Camera.main` is finished.

Then you can simply disable that `VuforiaCamera` that has the `VuforiaBehaviour` on it.

```
VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);

// Note: that part I'm just inventing since I did it different
// using reference etc. I hope vuforia does not destroy the Instance
// OnDisable .. otherwise you would need the reference instead of using Instance here
// but maybe it is already enough to just enable and disable the GameObject
VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.enabled = false;
```

By doing this the device's camera was "free" and PhotoCapture can now use it.

```
PhotoCapture.StartPhotoModeAsync(....
```

---

If you then need the camera again for vuforia, first stop the PhotoCapture

```
PhotoCapture.StopPhotoModeAsync(..
```

and then after it stopped in the callback re-enable the `ARCamera` (object with the `VuforiaBehaviour`) and the `VuforiaBehaviour` again.

---

Something like

```
private void Awake()
{
    var cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
    targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);

    // Create a PhotoCapture object
    PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, captureObject =>
    {
        photoCaptureObject = captureObject;
        cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
        cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
        cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
        cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;
    });
}

private void Update()
{
    // if not initialized yet don't take input
    if (photoCaptureObject == null) return;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("k"))
    {
        Debug.Log("k was pressed");

        VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        // Activate the camera
        photoCaptureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(cameraParameters, result =>
        {
           if (result.success)
           {
               // Take a picture
               photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
           }
           else
           {
               Debug.LogError("Couldn't start photo mode!", this);
           }
       });
    }
}

private static string FileName(int width, int height)
{
    return $"screen_{width}x{height}_{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.png";
}

private void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
{
    // Copy the raw image data into the target texture
    photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);

    Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();

    targetTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height), 0, 0);
    targetTexture.Apply();

    byte[] bytes = targetTexture.EncodeToPNG();

    string filename = FileName(Convert.ToInt32(targetTexture.width), Convert.ToInt32(targetTexture.height));
    //save to folder under assets
    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Snapshots/" + filename, bytes);
    Debug.Log("The picture was uploaded");

    // Deactivate the camera
    photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
}

private void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
{
    // Shutdown the photo capture resource
    photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
    photoCaptureObject = null;

    VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

---

The exception might however also be related to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/1790).

Comment: So I should have 2 cameras; one described above and one main camera?

Comment: Yes. The Vuforia camera doesn't even have to move at all. It is only used for accessing the devices real camera.

Comment: I still don't fully understand. So I have a maincamera tagged mainCamera and I have an ARcamera with the script on it with the camera and the vuforia behaviour components? Is the script on the right camera? Which camera should the canvas point to?

Comment: I added my setup. I noticed that I actually in my script additionally enable and disable the `VuforiaBehaviour` itself but it shouldn't make a difference. On all canvas etc where ever you need a Camera you continue using the "normal" mainCamera as before .. you only add the additional ARCamera with the setup as in the added picture

Comment: I still get the `Failed capturing photo (hr = 0xC00D3704)` error. I tried to have only `VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);` and then only `VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.enabled = false;` and then both of them, they act the same so it probably does not matter which one to use in my case :) These were added under start() (to make sure that it isn't on from the beginning), before `photoCaptureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync` and at the end in `OnStoppedPhotoMode`. Sry for being slow, but what am I missing?

Comment: This is how it looks in my project: When starting I see the canvas components through the hololens device. Clicking ´"k"` gives the error in the console. Right after that I see a strange live feed from the computer webcam through the hololens aswell as the canvas components. The strange thing about the live feed is the way it crops when looking at it, the image gets split somehow ^.^

Comment: Thank you @derHugo! This does not get the error anymore!